# logging into network share

Tags: windows-xp, networking, script, batch, network-shares

I am logging into a network share through a batch script to start a test 
I can get the shared program logged in but then up comes the windows prompt "run" or "cancel".  Not all of the machines have this prompt.

How can I automatically choose 'run' from this prompt so the rest of the script can run?

Jake

Answer (score 1):

Try using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) to run your batch file.  It can watch for windows by title or window handle and send keystrokes/mouse clicks as needed.

Comment: Actually the script is part of a larger AutoIT script.  I use the AutoIT to run commands in the program that is called.  My issue is that if I do get AutoIT to hit Run it doesn't come up on every machine so I am currently just using window position and a click.  Can I code an If into AutoIT to check whether the window comes up then click?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to set a timeout to look for that window (by title or handle) and if it doesn't come up within that specified period just continue.  It's been awhile since I've used AutoIt so I can't give you exact syntax, but it should be pretty straightforward. Sloppy pseudocode: loop(exit when count=10); if(window exists) click Run; else wait 1s; count++; end loop;